# Aspose PdfFileEditor Cutting off Pages

Tags: pdf, append, aspose

I have a function that takes non specified number of PDFs (in a `List`) and turns them into 1 PDF using the `PdfFileEditor.append` function, like so.

```
 pdfFileEditor.append(streams.get(x), streams.get(y), 1, 1500, outputStream);
```

The function that controls the merging is usually fine. Except there is 1 PDF in the application that seems to always eat anything that was appended before it.

For example, if we have 5 PDFs where number 3 is the bad one.

We can either use a forward loop (append 1 and 2, then 1&2 and 3, then 1&2&3 and 4, then 1&2&3&4 and 5) or a backwards loop (append 4 and 5, then 3 and 4&5, then 2 and 3&4&5, then 1 and 2&3&4&5) to combine the PDFs.

In a forward loop, we end up with only 3, 4, and 5 in the final PDF. In a backward loop, we end up with 1, 2, and 3 in the final PDF.

I am not sure what's wrong with PDF 3. It opens fine. But it does appear to be a dynamic PDF (has fields etc). I tried both forward and backwards loops because I thought maybe the PDF type was causing a reset to occur on the output stream somehow.

Has anyone seen the `append` method essentially just ignore a stream before?

**Notes**

1. I know this is a deprecated package from Aspose. But company standards means we cannot update to the new package.
2. Code is helpful - I can include the method, but it is long and the issue is clearly with the 1 PDF. Everything works in all cases except when a certain PDF is included in the list.

Comment: Please supply the PDF in question.

Comment: I think that's a good way to get me fired :)

Comment: That makes it hard to help, especially as the issue *is clearly with the 1 PDF* as you said. Probably you can try with other, non-sensitive documents. If you can reproduce the issue that way, @Nausherwan might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am social media developer at Aspose. I would suggest you to download and try the latest version of Aspose.Pdf at your end to see if the problematic file works fine with the latest version. Also, it would be better if you save your complete code, version of library you are using and the problematic file with us.

Comment: Sadly, company security prevents me from doing a lot of that. Downloading, sharing code, etc. I can say we are using a 4.4.0 pdf kit jar.

Comment: I did notice that the `concatenate` method worked fine, but put a licensing message at the top of the PDF.

Comment: Well, you are using a very older version of the API. Also, as you are saying that concatenate method worked fine, the license message will be due to license subscription expiry to use a new version.